# rxHadoopCopyFromLocal from Windows

Tags: r, hadoop, azure-hdinsight, microsoft-r

What is the right syntax to copy from Windows to a remote HDFS?

I'm trying to copy a file from my local machine to a remote hadoop cluster using RStudio

```
rxHadoopCopyFromLocal("C:/path/to/file.csv", "/target/on/hdfs/")
```

This throws

```
copyFromLocal '/path/to/file.csv': no such file or directory`
```

Notice the C:/ disappeared.

This syntax also fails

```
rxHadoopCopyFromLocal("C:\\path\\to\\file.csv", "/target/on/hdfs/")
```

with error

```
-copyFromLocal: Can not create a Path from a null string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake.

Turns out the rxHadoopCopyFromLocal command is a wrapper of the hdfs fs -copyFromLocal. All it does is copy from a local filesystem to an hdfs target.

In this case the `rxSetComputeContext(remotehost)` was set to a remote cluster. On the remote machine, there is not a C:\path\to\file.csv

Here are a couple of ways to get the files there.

**Configure local hdfs-site.xml for remote Hdfs Cluster**

- Ensure you have hadoop tools installed on your local machine
- Edit your local hdfs-site.xml to point to the remote cluster
- Ensure `rxSetComputeContext("local")`
- Run `rxHadoopCopyFromLocal("C:\local\path\to\file.csv", "/target/on/hdfs/")`

**SCP and Remote Compute Context**

- Copy your file to the remote machine with `scp C:\local\path\to\file.csv user@remotehost:/tmp`
- Ensure `rxSetComputeContext(remotehost)`
- Run `rxHadoopCopyFromLocal("/tmp/file.csv", "/target/on/hdfs/")`

Comment: MRS 9.1 also has `rxHadoopCopyFromClient` for copying to from a client a remote cluster. Not sure if it was in earlier versions though.

Answer (score 0):

The [dev version of dplyrXdf](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/dplyrXdf) now supports files in HDFS. You can upload a file from the native filesystem as follows; this works both from the edge node, *and* from a remote client.

```
hdfs_upload("c\\path\\to\\file.csv", "/target/on/hdfs")
```

If you have a *dataset* (an R object) that you want to upload, you can also use the standard dplyr `copy_to` verb. This will import the data to an Xdf file and upload it, returning an RxXdfData data source pointing to the uploaded file.

```
txt <- RxTextData("file.csv")
hd <- RxHdfsFileSystem()
hdfs_xdf <- copy_to(hd, txt, name="uploaded_xdf")
```